# Application Load Balancer pointing default nginx page, not my website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an EC2 instance. The inbound of security group for this instance is

[image]

The outbound is for all traffic.

I also created an application load balancer. The inbound of security group for this ALB is:
[image]

The outbound of security group for the ALB is:
[image]

The health check of ALB target group is also OK:
[image]

The DNS records are:
[image]

My website runs in a docker. Parts of docker-compose.yml are:

```
ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

I also tried using `- 80:8080` , but I could not start this container successfully because port 80 was listened by nginx.
The port information of my EC2 instance is as the following:
[image]

I tried to access my website through Chrome by typing my domain name in the address bar. But I got the following page:

### Welcome to nginx!

> If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed > and working. Further configuration is required. > > For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org. > Commercial support is available at nginx.com. > > Thank you for using nginx.

---

I think I should access my website page, but not nginx page. How can I fix this issue? I am struggling in it for 3 days. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to me that nginx is working. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my post to be clearer. I expect to access my web page, but not Nginx page.

Comment: You probably misconfigured nginx. nginx should redirect you to your website. That's the purpose of nginx.

Comment: try typing in the actual path of your application instead of just the domain name.

Comment: @Marcin Yes, it must be misconfigured somewhere. But I do not know where it is.

Comment: @Shameel Thanks for your reply. Actually my website can response the root path. I also tried as your suggestion, got 404 error.

Comment: 1) Why do you have Nginx installed? 2) Did you add port 8080 to the URL when you tried to access your container website? 3) As you have everything set up currently, Nginx should be responding on port 80 and your container should be responding on port 8080. Note: do not set up `outbound rules` unless you know exactly what you are doing. **Allow all outbound traffic**. What is your reasoning for only allowing the ALB to connect outbound to destinations on port 80?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all warm hearted guys. I already fixed it. The root reason was that I should not install and start nginx on my EC2 instance.All was OK after I stopped nginx running on my EC2 instance.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar issue. If Nginx shouldn't run on your AWS instance, then how does the ELB know where your page is?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is coming from your .conf file in your sites-available folder

```
sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/your.conf
```

add this new server block

```
server {
# Listen to requests from the load balancer
listen 80;
server_name example-loadbalancer.example.com;

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```

}